# Windows XP ISO looks for CD

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, iso-image

I created a windows XP iso from the windows xp installation CD I have, so I can upload the ISO to proxmox. When I boot the VM and try to install windows XP, it seems to ask for the CD. I assume this is because the MD5 hashes don't match. Is there anyway to fix this, so the iso hash and cd hash match?

I used the following command to rip:

```
 sudo dd if=/dev/cdrom of=windowsXPsp2.iso bs=blocksize count=volume size
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried dwith another ISO seeing if the VM boots. Have you tried ripping another bootable CD the same way and seeing if it boots. Have you tried seeing if that XP CD even boots? what commands are showing you that the cd and iso hashes don't match?

Comment: Well it boots. It's the installation that gives the error not proxmox.

Comment: what do you mean the installation gives the error?  If the VM asks for the CD then maybe it isn't even starting the windows installation

Comment: It says: "Windows XP home edition setup: setup could not read the CD you inserted or the CD is not a valid Windows CD"

Comment: Maybe the thing on the original CD is no good? Have you tried the CD in a proper computer?

Comment: include a screenshot

Comment: @barlop The CD has been used before in a proper computer. I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because you have an upgrade disc, not an installer disc. Upgrade discs must first verify that a previous installation of Windows exists first before it will start the installer. If you don't have windows previously installed, which is the case when building a new VM, then you may be able to by pass this but inserting an ISO of Windows 2000, 98, or ME. Otherwise, you will need to get ahold of an XP ISO that is not just an upgrade disc and doesn't require this check.